# $\sum_2^\infty\frac{1}{\log(n)^{\log(n)}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I need to check for the convergence of $\sum_2^\infty\frac{1}{\log(n)^{\log(n)}}$. But I have no idea how to proceed.

I tried using the fact that $\sum_2^\infty\frac{1}{\log(n)^{n}}$ converges, but to no avail.

Please help.

Comment: Use the Cauchy condensation test.

Comment: Use $\log n^{\log n} \ge (e^2)^{\log n}=n^2$ for $n\ge 3^9$